# Mpi does not support Opencv?

Tags: c, opencv, mpi

I'm using MPI and Opencv library files to write a c program into my raspberry pi. 
When my c program try to use opencv function like cvCreateImage and cvGet2D, it always give this error:

```
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   EXIT CODE: 11
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
```

this is my c program:

```
    #include <mpi.h>
    #include </home/pi/opencv-2.4.8/include/opencv/cv.h>
    #include </home/pi/opencv-2.4.8/include/opencv/highgui.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>

    #define MAXN 2048             /* max 2d fft size */
    #define EPSILON 0.00001       /* for comparing fp numbers */
    #define PI 3.14159265358979   /* 4*atan(1.0) */
    #define IMAGE_SIZE      1024
    #define NUM_CELLS       4
    #define IMAGE_SLICE     (IMAGE_SIZE / NUM_CELLS) //(512/4)=128
    #define SOURCE_PROCESSOR    0
    #define DEST_PROCESSOR      SOURCE_PROCESSOR
    typedef struct {int r,i;} mycomplex;
    int     numtasks;               /* Number of processors */
    int     taskid;                 /* ID number for each processor */
    int     checkpoint;
    int     dt[10], sum;



    int main(int argc,char *argv[])
    {
        int rc, cell, i, j, k, n, nx, logn, errors, sign, flops;
        float mflops;
        checkpoint=0;

    /*****************************************************************************/
        /* Initialize MPI environment and get task's ID and number of tasks 
            * in the partition. */
          rc = MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
          rc|= MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numtasks);
          rc|= MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&taskid);

        if(taskid==0)
        {
            //getimage();   
            IplImage *image;
            IplImage *grayimage;
            image=cvLoadImage("one.jpg",-1);
            grayimage=cvCreateImage(cvSize(image->width,image->height),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
            cvCvtColor(image,grayimage,CV_RGB2GRAY);

            for(i=0;i<image->height;i++)
            {

                for(j=0;j<image->width;j++)
                {
                    CvScalar scal=cvGet2D(image,i,j);
                    printf("(%d) ",(int)scal.val[0]);
                }
                printf("\n");       
            }
        cvWaitKey(0);
        cvReleaseImage(&image); 
        }
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        /* Must have 4 tasks for this program */
        if (numtasks != NUM_CELLS)
        {
           printf("Error: this program requires %d MPI tasks\n", NUM_CELLS);
            exit(1);
        }

        if (rc != MPI_SUCCESS)
           printf ("error initializing MPI and obtaining task ID information\n");
        else
             printf ("MPI task ID = %d\n", taskid);

       n = IMAGE_SIZE; //512
       /* compute logn and ensure that n is a power of two */
       nx = n;
       logn = 0;
       while(( nx >>= 1) > 0)
          logn++;           //logn=9 when nx=1 
       nx = 1;
       for (i=0; i<logn; i++)   //loop 9 times
          nx = nx*2;        //nx=nx*(2^9)=512
       if (nx != n)         //nx=512 = n=512 proved
       {
          (void)fprintf(stderr, "%d: fft size must be a power of 2\n", IMAGE_SIZE);
          exit(0);
       }
       .....
```

The make file I use seems fine:

```
mpi_2dfft: mpi_2dfft.o   /home/pi/mpich2/lib/libmpich.a
    /home/pi/mpich2/bin/mpicc -o mpi_2dfft mpi_2dfft.o -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann -lwiringPi -lwiringPiDev -lpthread -lm
```

May I know that why opencv function can't be use in mpi?
Do mpi conflict with other libraries?

Comment: I suspect that your OpenCV call crashes on one of the processes, which brings down the others. Did you test the OpenCV code on a single process without MPI?

Comment: `MPI_Finalize()` should be called before exiting main. Could you try to add `MPI_Finalize()` before `exit()` commands and at the end of your code ?

Comment: yes, I tested it on a single process, it worked. How can I make it won't crash in MPI? This is just part of my c program, I have MPI_Finalize() at the end of program. My problem is just opencv function can't be use in MPI program. Thanks

Comment: The code you placed in your question works fine on my computer, even with MPI and 4 procs : i am not able to reproduce your problem. Are you sure that your problem does not come from `...` at the end of your code ? What are the outputs of `mpicc --showme`, `which mpicc`, which mpirun` and `mpirun -version` ? This could tell you if the version of mpicc corresponds to the version of mpirun (or mpiexec)

Comment: I found my problem. I used 4 of the 256MB Ram Raspberry Pi to run MPI and Opencv  program at the same time. The Ram is not enough for it to execute MPI function. Now I change all to 512MB Ram and it works. Thank You. (I love this website!!) :D